# GraphView, how to show x-axis label?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm trying to plot graph using GraphView library. My problem is, the x-axis does not show up but the y-axis can. Besides, the value at the x-axis label also not showing up.

Here is my xml file:

```
    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FAFA82" />
```

and the java code:

```
double graph1LastXValue = 5d;
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("Match Value");
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalAxisTitle("Time/s");
Series2 = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
mSeries1.setColor(Color.RED);
mSeries1.setThickness(2);
graph.addSeries(mSeries2);
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(100);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridStyle.BOTH);
plotter(matchValMean);

protected void plotter(Double matchVal) {
matchValue = matchVal;
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mTimer1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
            graph1LastXValue += 1d;
            mSeries1.appendData(new DataPoint(graph1LastXValue, matchValue), true, 100);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 1000);
}
```

I did not show all the codes because it is very long. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show X Axis's title

```
GridLabelRenderer gridLabel = graphView.getGridLabelRenderer();
gridLabel.setHorizontalAxisTitle("X Axis Title");
```

If you want to show X Axis's label, based on [this](http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/migration-from-31-to-40) documentation

```
// GraphView 3.x
graphView.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"2 days ago", "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow"});
graphView.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"high", "middle", "low"});

// GraphView 4.x
StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"old", "middle", "new"});
staticLabelsFormatter.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"low", "middle", "high"});
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
```

Comment: It is working on Demo project which means with single activity but it is not working on my live projects, Any issues?